# python - Parse XML with unicode characters into ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I'm using [PDFminer](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six), but it contains a bug and I get the following invalid XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string size="16">&#244;&#130;&#204;&#2;f&#198;&#135;&#143;&#11;*&#154;&#23;]&#214;&#20;[</string>
```

When I'm trying to parse it with `ElementTree` I'm getting the following error:

```
    bookXml = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(filename)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 1, column 36
```

I think best way to handle this case is to fix XML first, but how?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `&#2;` (and a few others) that equals `U+0002`, that AFAIK is not a valid character in a XML file.

Comment: Oh, XML version is `"1.1"`!! You don't see that everyday. Then I guess that the `U+0002` is correct after all, but you'll have a hard time finding compatible tools...

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the offending XML string in CDATA. Confirmed working as soon as I did this. Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string><![CDATA[&#244;&#130;&#204;&#2;&#198;&#135;&#143;&#11;*&#154;&#23;&#214;&#20;]]></string>
```

More about CDATA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean).

Comment: This is only temporary solution, because now I need to call `html.unescape()` to get required value.